# Hide irrelevant decimal fractional part of numbers in spreadsheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets, cell-format

Is there any way to format numbers in 123/Excel-compatible spreadsheet applications, Google Spreadsheets in particular, in a way that hides the fractional part *and the preceding decimal separator* (i.e. dot or comma depending on locale) if it is zero (i.e. the number is an integer)?

### 123

- `0.0` → 123.0
- `0.#` → 123. *this is the closest I get*
- `0.?` → 123.␠
- `0_.0` → 123 0
- `0_.#` → 123
- `0_.?` → 123 ␠

### 1.23

- `0.0%` → 123.0%
- `0.#%` → 123.%
- `0.?%` → 123. %
- `0_.0%` → 123 0%
- `0_.#%` → 123 %
- `0_.?%` → 123  %

I know that one can format positive, negative and zero-value numbers separately with semicolons: `+0.0%;−0.0%;±0_.?%`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel number format adds decimal point for whole numbers](https://superuser.com/questions/1424812/excel-number-format-adds-decimal-point-for-whole-numbers)

Comment: Apparently, I used the wrong search terms and the answer is “itʼs not possible with number formatting character codes alone, but together with conditional formatting if formulas, `ROUND()` in particular, are supported therein”.